# How can i use form toolkit to change the bordercolor of composite?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I want to change the border color  of the composite  using form tool kit.But the result is something unexpected.It sets the background to white.

CODE:

```
 FormColors formColor = new FormColors(Display.getCurrent());
    formColor.createColor(FormColors.BORDER, 160, 32, 240);
    formColor.setForeground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 160, 32, 240));

    FormToolkit formToolkit = new FormToolkit(formColor);
    formToolkit.paintBordersFor(composite);
    Composite child=formtoolkit.createcomposite(composite)
     formtoolkit.paintBordersFor(child)
```

But this code has no effect on the border of the composite .an anyone tell me what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you need to add the following code to update your border color internally:

```
formColor.setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 255, 255, 255));
```

Source: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61092.html

Comment: Remember that you have to dispose any `Color` you create yourself!